# AMPL, selecting data from two sets

Tags: ampl

I have two sets which are:

```
set s1 := 0 1 5 6 ;
set s2 := 3 4 8 9 ;
```

I need to have a constraint which selects the data from these sets like the following line:

```
subject to sym1{i in 0..3 , j in 0..3 : i=j } : x[0,s1[i],0] = x[1,s1[j],0];
```

It means selecting data from s1 and s2 should be like: 
`x[0,0,0] = x[1,3,0];`
`x[0,1,0] = x[1,4,0];`
`x[0,5,0] = x[1,8,0];`
`x[0,6,0] = x[1,9,0];`

But the code I wrote has a syntax error.
Would you please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is by declaring sets as `ordered` and using the `member` function to an element of a set by its index:

```
set s1 ordered := {0, 1, 5, 6};
set s2 ordered := {3, 4, 8, 9};

subject to sym1{i in 1..4}: x[0, member(i, s1), 0] = x[1, member(i, s2), 0];
```

Alternatively, you can replace sets with parameters:

```
param s1{1..4};
param s2{1..4};

subject to sym1{i in 1..4}: x[0, s1[i], 0] = x[1, s2[i], 0];

data;

param s1 :=
 1 0
 2 1
 3 5
 4 6;

param s2 :=
 1 3
 2 4
 3 8
 4 9;
```